# What can we use instead of Hardware acceleration for smooth bitmap drawing in android

Tags: android, bitmap, hardware-acceleration

I am developing a Drawing app in which drawing multiple bitmap on touch position.But in some devices drawing slowing with lag so i create different values folder in which add Boolean value true and false according device versions for hardware acceleration in android manifest But in android thousands of devices available.

So what is the easiest way for implement all devices and what can i use instead of hardware accelaration